how to prevent the hls video player dont refresh when m3u8 changes
here i am using ffmpeg to use camera and audio to make a hls stream on server as the stream continious old m3u8 components deletes and new ones gets added to main.m3u8. but as we insert the url of hls stream file main.m3u8. the player refreshes as soon as the file gets rewritten because of new and old ones.         so
i have tried to change the players like hls.js or videojs etc none were to solve this. how to solve this and make sure the stream runs smoothly.
Server.js
const startStreaming = (viddev,auddev) => {
    if (ffmpegProcess) {
        ffmpegProcess.kill();
    }
    const segmentDuration = 10;
    const outputFilename = './video/output.m3u8';
    const ffmpegCommand = `ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="${viddev}" -f dshow -i audio="${auddev}" -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -codec:a aac -b:a 128k -hls_time ${segmentDuration} -hls_list_size 3 -hls_flags delete_segments -start_number 0 -hls_segment_type mpegts ${outputFilename}`;

    ffmpegProcess = exec(ffmpegCommand);

    ffmpegProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`ffmpeg stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    ffmpegProcess.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`ffmpeg process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
};

app.use('/video', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'video')));

// Endpoint to list audio and video devices
app.get('/devices', async (req, res) => {
    const data=await parseDevices()
    // console.log(data.cameras[0].name)
    startStreaming(data.cameras[0].name,data.microphones[0].name);
    res.json(data)
});

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Video.js HLS Player</title>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.10.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <video
        id="video"
        class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
        controls
        autoplay
        preload="auto"
        width="640"
        height="268"
        data-setup='{"autoplay": true, "liveui": true}'>
        <source src="https://localhost:3000/video/output.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
    </video>

    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.10.0/video.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Initialize Video.js player
        var player = videojs('video', {
            autoplay: 'play',
            liveui: true  // Enable the live UI for live streams
        });

        // Seek to live when the player is ready
        player.ready(function() {
            player.liveTracker.on('liveedgechange', function() {
                player.currentTime(player.liveTracker.liveCurrentTime());
            });
        });

        // Handle any errors encountered by Video.js
        player.on('error', function() {
            console.error('Video.js encountered an error:', player.error());
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>



FFmpeg will overwrite that file... that's what it's supposed to do.  The file will reference either other segments or other playlist files.  Can you elaborate on what the actual problem is?  Also, you should be very cautious... the way you're executing FFmpeg does not escape any of the parameters.  Consider using spawn() instead of exec(), as spawn allows you to pass in an array of parameters which never touch a shell.

here i want to have the player to play the hls or m3u8 video smoothly. but since the ffmpeg makes a new video packet of m3u8 for each 10 seconds the main packet output.m3u8 gets changed which triggers the reload of video player page.  so i want to know how can i avoid this rerender of video player

But, that's how HLS works.  Just a big pile of files of media segments, with playlists that are updated to reference them.  The player knows this and will stick all the segments end-to-end into a buffer so that playback appears smooth.
